# Anything wrong with this MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT id FROM articles WHERE position =? LIMIT 1");
$stmt-> bind_param('i',$call );
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch();
$oldpostid = $result;
$stmt->close();
```

I don't see anything wrong with it, but it is returning 1 or nothing. `$call` is set and integer. I tried this too:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE position =? LIMIT 1");
$oldpostid = $result['id'];
```

Comment: $call is a number between 1-4. And I know it is working. The funny thing is i put this statement through phpmyadmin and it came back perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is all working you need to bind the result variables as well.  [`mysqli_stmt_fetch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) returns a boolean:

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id);
$stmt->fetch();
$oldpostid = $id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think this will help. It's part of a larger page of code so I will focus elsewhere fore the code

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing mysqli & PDO. The first line is [**PDO**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT id FROM articles WHERE position =? LIMIT 1");
```

The next line is [**mysqli**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

```
$stmt-> bind_param('i',$call );
```

Should be for PDO the  unnamed variables in place holder [**Manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) Example 4

```
$stmt-> bindParam(1,$call );
$stmt->execute();
```

OR  [using array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

```
$stmt->execute(array($call));
```

Comment: Indeed, I do not really know the difference. I shall investigate!